# Attribute for storing additional info

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few links:

```
<a href="div1">link1</a>
<a href="div2">link2</a>
<a href="div3">link3</a>
```

And containers:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

When a user clicks on a link the script gets container's Id from href attribute and shows correct div. But i don't want to use href attribute for that purpose. Is there any standard attribute for storing additional info?

Comment: Neir... just a reminder (5! unaccepted answers) Give your contribution to the community by accepting the answer you like. (you don't have to hurry, to allow late answerers - answer. but I think that a week delay should be fine. Don't you?! )

Comment: Yeah! I did not know that it's so important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).  They're non-standard for HTML revisions less than 5, but jQuery honors them: [jQuery Data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-* attributes.

```
<a href="div1" data-id="div1">link1</a>
<a href="div2" data-id="div2">link2</a>
<a href="div3" data-id="div3">link3</a>
```

And you can access the value from `element.dataset.id`

Edit: If you want to support older browsers too, you can use `rel` attribute.

Comment: Only for HTML5.  Older browsers have no idea what you're talking about.  You can still access them for older browsers, but you'll need a library.  Fortunately, jQuery provides one.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that data attributes are an HTML5 feature.